# How do I get the next record in table with linq?

Tags: linq

I have a table Orders like this:

ID

CustomerID

name

ID CustomerID name
1    4          aa

5    6         bbb

4    9          ccc

8    10         ddd

first ordering the table,then get the next row.....  How to do?
if current row id is 4 ,i want to get the row where id==5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
Orders.OrderBy(x=>x.ID).Skip(1).Take(1)
```

**Edit:** If I understand your question now:

```
Orders.OrderBy(x=>x.ID).Where(x=>x.ID>4).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: ID CustomerID name
1    4         aaa

5    6         bbb

4    9         ccc

8    10        ddd

if current row id is 4 ,i want to get the row where id==5